# Files inside the assets folder are not being loaded in sub pages

Tags: node.js, express

I have a folder structure like below

- assets

  - bootstrap
  - css

    - style.css
  - js

    - jquery.min.js
- views

  - partials

    - head.ejs
    - header.ejs
    - scripts.ejs
  - home.ejs
  - user_registration.ejs

In my app.js file I have set this assets folder like:

```
var app = express();
app.use('/static', express.static('assets'));
var routes = require('./routes/routes');
```

In my routes.js file

```
exports.userLogin = function(req, res){
    var userLogin = req.params.userId;
    var users = memberData.users;
    res.render('user_registration', {
        title : 'Welcome',
        users : users
    });
};
```

In my head.ejs file

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static/css/style.css" type="text/css">
```

Now inside in user_registration file, I have following code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <% include partials/head.ejs %>
</head>
<body>
    <% include partials/scripts.ejs %>
</body>
</html>
```

By using this my jQuery, bootstrap files that are inside assets folder are not being loaded. But the home.ejs page is working normally.
When I check at the console, the home.ejs page is taking those files in following format 
http://localhost:3000/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

whereas user_registration page is taking following format

http://localhost:3000/user_registration/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css

I am very new in express.js framework, so I could not figure out how to solve this problem. Can anybody please help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem is here `app.use('/static', express.static('assets'));` in your code line. 
Replace it with
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'assets')));` 
And in your head.ejs file replace bootstrap css calling line 
`href="static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"` to `href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"`


Hop you understand.

Comment: `app.use('/static', ...` is pretty fine, it means host the target static resource under `/static` namespace

Comment: I told you how did I do it. Ok fine, then use path without `/static` in the href

Answer (score 1):

The problem is: the `href` link to static resource should be absolute, not relative. Specifically, in `head.ejs` it should be:

```
href="/static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
...
href="/static/css/style.css"
```

NOT:

```
href="static/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css"
...
href="static/css/style.css"
```

As `app.use('/static', express.static('assets'));` stated, the static assets are hosted under `/static` namespace (absolute URL starting with `/static`), it doesn't make any sense to use relative URL any more.